# android aapt source code compile error

Tags: android, build, aapt

I had bulid the android source code (android 5.0) successfully,then i modify the aapt source code and want to build the aapt only. I cd to the appt dir and use mm command, the error is :

```
ybwang@ybwang-VirtualBox:~/Documents/Android/android-5.0.0_r2/frameworks/base/tools/aapt$ mm
============================================
    PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
    PLATFORM_VERSION=5.0
    TARGET_PRODUCT=full
    TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
    TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
    TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
    TARGET_ARCH=arm
    TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
    TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
    TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
    TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
    TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
    HOST_ARCH=x86_64
    HOST_OS=linux
    HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.13.0-32-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
    HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
    BUILD_ID=LRX21M
    OUT_DIR=out
    ============================================
    make: Entering directory `/home/ybwang/Documents/Android/android-5.0.0_r2'
    Export includes file: frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt_intermediates/export_includes
    Import includes file: out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/import_includes
    Export includes file: frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/export_includes
    make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libexpat_static_intermediates/export_includes', needed by `out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/import_includes'.  Stop.
    make: Leaving directory `/home/ybwang/Documents/Android/android-5.0.0_r2'

#### make failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ####
```

how to solve this problem? can someone help me? 
thanks